# Using FITS file to plot dispersion relation graph problem

Tags: plotting, fits-format

I'm using a FITS file to plot the dispersion relation $\left( \omega-\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2} \right)$ of solar wave.
However, it failes to work.
I think there may be errors about the FITS files imported, or the code may be wrong.
Can you help me fix it?

The following is the code and the files used:

```
file = Image /@Import["D:\\wolfram\\MMAFiles\\SolarPhysicsHomework\\june19.fits",{"Data", 1}];(* Import the file *)
size = Flatten[{ImageDimensions[file[[1]]],Dimensions[file]}];(* obtain the size of file, including the images resolution and number of images *)
u = size[[1]]; v = size[[2]]; w = size[[3]];(* each dimension of the size of the file *)
pow = Fourier[ImageData[file[[#]]]] & /@ Range[w];(* FFT *)
temp = Table[0, u, w/2];
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i], {1, u/2}]
Table[ii = Round[Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]];
  temp[[ii, k]] = temp[[ii, k]] + Abs[pow[[i, j, k]]]^2,
  {i, 1, u/2}, {j, 1, v/2}, {k, 1, w/2}];
p1 = temp[[1 ;; u/2]];
ArrayPlot[p1, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Rescale[Log[#], Log[MinMax[p1]]]] &)]
```

[Here is the files I'm using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QtrVa8nubW4jThpfIIBretJzd64RVvQf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to open access to the file. Currently it appears as access denied.

Comment: I have updated the link, and it should be available with anyone this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues. The first one is that you have some partially corrupted files (either dead pixels, highly unlikely as the are not single rows, or bad readouts). I have manage to locate some: files 17, 41, 42 and 76. For example

```
probFiles = {{17}, {41}, {42}, {76}};
GraphicsRow[Flatten[Table[file[[i]], {i, probFiles}]], ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

I do not know if there are more of these images (you have to check). Note that the pixel value of the inactive ones is 0.43570240076063704`. So I recommend to remove those, as they are going to add a lot of noise in your Fourier trasform:

```
file = Delete[file, probFiles]
```

But this does not solve entirely your problem since if you know plot the results you will get:

```
ArrayPlot[p1,ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[Log[#], Log[MinMax[p1]]]] &)]
```

[image]

The reason for this is that the first value of the squared modulus of the FourierTransform at zero frequency (given the default FourierParameters {0,1}) is simply
$$\frac{\text{Sum}[\text{pixelValues}]^2}{\text{number of pixels}}$$
if you select a different pair of Fourier Parameters e.g.{-1,1} then the squared modulus of the FourierTransform at zero frequency will be the mean value of your pixels squared.
$$\text{Mean}[\text{pixelValues}]^2$$

Given the fact that this is a very large constant value it will saturate your scale even if it is logarithimic. Thus, you can either omit the zero frequency or you can simply subtract the mean value of the pixels before taking the Fourier transform.

By ommiting the first bin you get:

```
ArrayPlot[Map[Rest, temp[[1 ;; u/2]]],ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[Log[#], Log[MinMax[p1]]]] &)]
```

[image]